# How to implement constraints that are external to a microservice?

Tags: microservices

Suppose we have two microservices, Customers and Orders, with no dependencies between them, i.e. they don't call each other, they don't know each other.  Every order, though, has a reference to a customer by means of a customer id. In other words one customer may have zero or more orders, and one order belongs to exactly one customer.

For the sake of the example, it's totally fine to delete a customer **unless** there are orders belonging to that customer.  What is the most appropriate way to implement a constraint on Customers that prevents a customer from being deleted if one or more orders have a reference to that customer? Analogous to referential integrity in a relational database.

These are the approaches I can think of:

1. Let Customers ask Orders if a given customer has any orders, e.g. via API call.
2. Let Customers keep track of which orders are assigned to every customer, e.g. by having each customer record maintain a list of order ids.
3. Merge Customers and Orders into a single microservice and manage it internally.

I'm not sure which approach is the best for the given example in a microservices context. I can see pros and cons in all three approaches but I won't list them here because I'd like to hear other people's thoughts on the problem, including approaches not listed above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the second approach would help if you're going to decouple through events, either tracking a list of ids or a counter just telling how many orders are stored for such a Customer.

On the Order microservice you will emit an event when there is a creation/deletion that will be captured by the Customer (or any other microservice interested) who will take care of updating the list of order ids (or increment/reduce the counter).

If customer order counter is 0 then you may delete the customer.

Comment: Indeed this seems to be the best approach in terms of microservice independence. The only concern that would keep me awake at night is data inconsistency. If somehow Customers fails to receive or process the event, or Orders fails to send the event, then customer data becomes inconsistent. Putting mechanisms in place to detect and fix inconsistencies may not be hard when you have only one such place to watch, but it may be become impractical if you have to watch many other places like that.

Comment: Yeah, there's always a price to pay. Brokers such as `kafka` may help you achieving such a goal, but when you introduce eventual consistency then you must take particular care of not losing any event (or not to process more than once...)

Comment: Agreed. The way I see it, it's not even a matter of eventual consistency, it's a problem of permanent inconsistency and how to deal with it without getting your hands dirty on production data.

Comment: By the way, I came to know a very interesting project that can help in that sense: [Debezium](https://debezium.io/). Have a look if you're still interested in the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with your third approach: This will not work in a Microservice world, because you will always have those constraints between some Services. And if you want to solve all of them this way, you'll end up with a Monolith - and that's the end of your Microservice story.

The first and second approach have both the same *"problem"*: These are async operations, that may return false positive (or false negative) results: **It's possible to make api requests for `delete customer` and `create order` (or `delete order`) at the same time.**

Though this **can** happen:

- For your first approach: Customer Service asks Order Service if there are any Orders for this Customer. Order Service returns `0`. And at the same time Order Service creates a new Order for that Customer in another thread. So you end up with a deleted Customer and still created an Order.
- The same applies for your second approach: The messaging between those services is async. Though it's possible that Customer Service knows of `0` Orders, and permits the delete. But at the same time the Order Service creates a new Order for this Customer. And the `OrderCreated` message will hit the Customer Service after the Customer has already been deleted.
- If you try to do it the other way around, you'll end up with the same situation: Your Order Service could listen to `CustomerDeleted` messages, and then disallow creating new Orders for this Customer. But again: This message **can** arrive while there are still Orders in the database for this Customer.

Of course this is very unlikely to happen, but it still is possible and you cannot prevent it in an async Microservice world without transactions (which of course you want to avoid).

You should better ask yourself: *How should the system handle Orders where the corresponding Customer has been deleted?*

The answer to this question is most likely dependent on your business rules. For example: If the Order Service receives a `CustomerDeleted` message, it may be okay to simply delete all Orders from this Customer. Or maybe the behavior depends on the Order's `state` property: It's okay to delete all Orders with `state = draft`, but every other Order from this Customer should still be processed and shipped as usual.